# Do I just call a single run of session to run all operation in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, I assume I have something like:

```
run1 = tf.assign(y,x)
run2 = tf.assign(z,y)
sess.run(run2, feed_dict={x:a}
```

Will this call first run1, then run2, or do I need to explicitly call run1 first?

I'm having trouble with other code I have. Is this error related at all?

> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   Variable_11    [[node Variable_11/read (defined at
>   :20) ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title, not always the case, an example where it is true:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector1")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector2")
mul1 = tf.multiply(x, y)
mul2 = tf.multiply(mul1, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(mul2, feed_dict={x: 2, y: 3}))
```

The operators are all connected, x, and y are inputs provided in the sess.run, and I request mul2, therefore mul1 will first have to be calculated, which will happen automatically in the same sess.run.

Example where it is not the case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector1")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector2")
mul1 = tf.multiply(x, y)
mul2 = tf.multiply(y, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(mul2, feed_dict={x: 2, y: 3}))
```

To calculate mul2, there is no need for mul1, so tensorflow wont be bothered with it.
To see which operators are connected you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector1")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="input_vector2")
mul1 = tf.multiply(x, y)
mul2 = tf.multiply(mul1, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.summary.FileWriter("path/to/empty/folder", sess.graph)
```

This script will log a logfile to a folder, this logfile can then be read with

> `tensorboard --logdir=path/to/empty/folder`

for more info about tensorboard I refer to [the official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)

The error you have is because you did not run     `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, this initializes all variables

Comment: When is it necessary to run global_variables_initializer? The code I'm basing off of doesn't use this at all

Comment: Simple answer would be, when you get that error. But Tensorflow uses weights and internal parameters in their operators sometimes, things that need to be trained, those parameters need to be initialised. I'm not 100% sure, since it has been a long time, but I don't think my coding examples need that method

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should run below code in order to eliminate the error.

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

After, you should call run1 and run2 respectively to assign a to z. But if you want to assign a to z with run2, you should define run2 as follow:

```
run2 = tf.assign(z, run1)
```

With this code, when you try to call run2, run1 will run and the result of run1 will assign to z.

Comment: I don't understand why my method doesn't work. If I just call run2, tensorflow should know that it first needs to do run1 and then run2. right?

Comment: Because, when you call run2, TensorFlow assigns y to z. How could TensorFlow know that run1 should be called? It does not assign x to y, because there is no reason to run run1. The feed_dict={x:a} code does not mean run1 need to be called first. As I mentioned before, if you assign the output of the run1 to z, then TensorFlow calls first run1 to obtain its output and assign to z.

Comment: Well I thought that since "y" was not initialized to anything, TF would know that it needs to initialize it, and the argument feed_dict "x"  is not even within run2. ALso, since x->y and y->z, I thought TF would construct a graph from x to z

Comment: Yes, you should define as follows:
run1 = tf.assign(y,x)
with tf.control_dependencies([run1]):
    run2 = tf.assign(z,y)

Then, when you call sess.run(run2, feed_dict={x:a}), firstly run1 is performed.